# How to use query parameter in Graphiql tool

Tags: node.js, reactjs, api, graphql, axios

I am using zomato api to make an restaurant review app with React, node and Graphql. As per the docuemnt, I am passing query parameters, but in graphiql tool I am getting 'Not defined'.

Here is the error:

[graphiql tool error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vk03v.png)

Here is the api documentation reference:

```
curl -X GET --header "Accept: application/json" --header "user-key: abc" "https://developers.zomato.com/api/v2.1/restaurant?res_id=2"
```

My query is how can we test the api using query parameters in graphiql tool? Also let me know how can we update the query parameter in api to catch user input and correspondingly show the result.

Below is the code for schema.js which defined graphql schema

```
const axios = require("axios");

const {
  GraphQLObjectType,
  GraphQLString,
  GraphQLInt,
  GraphQLBoolean,
  GraphQLList,
  GraphQLFloat,
  GraphQLSchema
} = require("graphql");

const RestaurantType = new GraphQLObjectType({
   name: "Restaurant",
   fields: () => ({
   res_id: {
     type: GraphQLInt
   },
   name: {
     type: GraphQLString
   },
   url: {
     type: GraphQLString
   },
   photos_url: {
     type: GraphQLString
   },

    menu_url: {
     type: GraphQLString
   }, 

   rating: {
     type: UserRatingType
   },

   location: {
     type: LocationType
    }
  })
});

const UserRatingType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: "UserRating",
  fields: () => ({
    aggregate_rating: {
      type: GraphQLFloat
     }
    })
   });

const LocationType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: "Location",
  fields: () => ({
    address: {
      type: GraphQLString
     },
    locality: {
      type: GraphQLString
    },
    zipcode: {
      type: GraphQLInt
    }
  })
});

const userKey = 'abc';
const RootQuery = new GraphQLObjectType({
name: "RootQueryType",
  fields: {
    restaurants: {
      type: new GraphQLList(RestaurantType),
      resolve(parent, args) {
        return axios
          .get(`https://developers.zomato.com/api/v2.1/restaurant`, {
              headers: {
                'user-key': {userKey}
              }})
            .then(res => res.data)
            .catch((error) => {
              console.log('error is ' + error);
            });
      }
    },

    restaurant: {
      type: RestaurantType,
      args: {
        res_id: {
          type: GraphQLInt
        }
      },
      resolve(parent, args) {
        return axios
          .get(`https://developers.zomato.com/api/v2.1/restaurant? 
 res_id`, {
           params: {
              res_id
           },
           headers: {
             'user-key': {
               userKey
             }
            }
          })
          .then(res => {
            console.log(res.data)})
          .catch((error) => {
            console.log('error is ' + error);
          });
      }
    }
  }
});

module.exports = new GraphQLSchema({
  query: RootQuery
});
```

Comment: put `res_id` in quotes

Comment: In graphql `request` object is received in the `resolver`'s third argument and you can look at it to find your `res_id` query parameter there

Comment: @Kishan, tried quotes, but still not working